# Fork stopping execution after completion

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork

I am trying to achieve this command in C using a pipe and a fork.

```
    cat /proc/<pid>/limits | 
    grep "Max file size \|Max open files\|Max processes\|Max pending signals"
```

It processes the entire command fine. Problem is, the parent case is causing execution to be stopped after it completes. No errors, no warning. My guess it is a pipe/file descriptor issue.

Code:

```
char * command[3];
char str[25] = "";

strcat(str, "/proc/");
strcat(str, pid);
strcat(str, "/limits");

command[0] = "cat";
command[1] = str;
command[2] = NULL;

int fd2[2];
pipe(fd2);
pid_t pidlimits;

 switch (pidlimits = fork()) {
        case 0:
            //Execute cat /proc/$pid/limits here
            dup2(fd2[1], 1);
            close(fd2[0]);
            execvp(command[0], command);
            exit(1);

        default:
            dup2(fd2[0], 0);
            close(fd2[1]);

            //Build the grep command here
            char * command2[3];                
            char grepFilter[100] = "\"\\|Max file size\\|Max pending signals\\|Max processes\\|Max open files\\|\"";

            command2[0] = "grep";
            command2[1] = grepFilter;
            command2[2] = NULL;

            execvp(command2[0], command2);
            exit(1);
    }            
}
```

Comment: What do you have the `exit` there for, if you don't want execution to end?

Comment: The command[] and command2[] arrays need to have 3 elements, the last element being a NULL pointer. Can you check whether either of your `execvp` calls fail?

Comment: `man execvp: The  exec() functions return only if an error has occurred.`

Comment: @Beta, i thought that under a fork that it will only hit the exit statements if execvp was unsucessful. Is that not true?

Comment: @user3281114, that's true. So maybe your `execvp` has failed? Why not try checking its output?

Comment: Pay attention to Mark's comment.  It calls out a serious flaw in your program.  If addressing that does not resolve your situation, then please consider explaining more clearly what "the parent case is causing execution to be stopped after it completes" means.  How do you know the locus of the problem if there is no output?  And if everything completed successfully, then what behavior did you expect *other than* the program stopping?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, i addressed and tested the issue Mark pointed out. However, the problem continues. I am attempting to get limits of a PID and pipe it into grep for specific lines. The reason i believe the issue lies within the parent case is because if the grep command is removed, the process completes and does not exit. So the problem resides in either the execution of the grep or piping to the grep.

Comment: You didn't put the above code in context.  If the problem is that you wanted your program to continue with some other action after the `cat` / `grep` business, then the problem is exactly what EOF pointed out: the `exec()` functions *do not return* if they are successful.  Your process forks once, and both parent and child execute an `execvp()`.  Unless something fails, control does not return to the original program.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. so the solution would be to setup another fork?

Comment: Yes, set up another fork in which to run your `grep` if you want the main process to perform other work afterward.  The main process should collect both children via `wait()` or `waitpid()` if it does not intend to exit soon thereafter, but it does not need to do so immediately if it does not need the children to finish before it proceeds.

Comment: Also, the parent should close both ends of its copy of the pipe.

Comment: Clearly I goofed in not noticing the `execvp`; at the risk of putting my other foot in my mouth, I suggest using `system` instead of setting up another `fork`, `execvp` and associated plumbing.

Comment: Well, `system()` could do the job, but it's a lot heavier weight because it runs the given command via the shell.  Also, there would still be a little dance involved in setting up the pipe correctly.  Personally, I think (direct) fork / exec for both children yields a cleaner solution.

Answer (score -1):

It appears you may have the child (case 0:) and parent (default:) reversed from what you intend. At least from what the example [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html) shows -- child is the pipe reader, parent is the pipe writer.

Comment: This does not explain the termination problem, and it is not consistent with the OP's assertion that the `cat` and `grep` combination in fact works as expected.  Indeed, in this case, the `cat` command running in the child is correctly set up as the writer, and the `grep` command running in the parent is correctly set up as the reader.  That's all correct, as far as it goes.